# Python ESL not working with apache mod-wsgi

Tags: python, apache

I created a web app that uses ESL to manage Freeswitch server.
When used command "ESLconnection("localhost", "8021", "ClueCon")", in my code to connect to freeswitch server, apache froze permanently.

```
class ESLconnection:
    __swig_setmethods__ = {}
    __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, ESLconnection, name, value)
    __swig_getmethods__ = {}
    __getattr__ = lambda self, name: _swig_getattr(self, ESLconnection, name)
    __repr__ = _swig_repr

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print('before this')
        this = apply(_ESL.new_ESLconnection, args)
        print('after this')
        try:
            self.this.append(this)
        except:
            self.this = this
```

**My debug logs:**

```
[Tue Nov 18 10:53:18.103572 2014] [error] before connection
[Tue Nov 18 10:53:18.103572 2014] [error] before this
[Tue Nov 18 10:53:18.103572 2014] [:info] [pid 13285] mod_wsgi (pid=13285): Daemon
process deadlock timer expired, stopping process 'localhost'. 
[Tue Nov 18 10:53:18.103781 2014] [:info] [pid 13285] mod_wsgi (pid=13285):
Shutdown requested 'localhost'.`enter code here`
```

Anything would help at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used [eventsocket](https://github.com/fiorix/eventsocket) lib, and it works very well with Apache mod_wsgi.

thank you